How to restore StartLayout from an unbootable Windows?
Is there any way how to restore the StartLayout (icon arrangement in Start menu) from unbootable Windows drive?
I can't login into any Windows account. So I can't Export Layout via PowerShell or Registry (HKCU).
I'm only able to start the Windows recovery menu with a command line.
My NVMe disk with the Windows 10 is decrypted and folders and files are available on another machine.
Story behind:
Something happened to my Windows 10 (22H2). The Windows can't display a Login screen, I see only a black screen before a Login screen.
I've tried to fix this issue throughout the Recovery menu via an automatic repair, to clone drive to an another NVMe drive, to check disk integrity - chkdsk, to check a system integrity - sfc, to fix boot partition - bootrec but without any success.
I have come to terms with the fact that I'm not able to get my old Windows account.
So I restored all my old folders & files and almost all settings from previous the Windows account except StartLayout.
It's not hard to me to rearrange the Start Menu Layout in my new Windows account to as the same as in old Windows account but I'm curious if there is any way how to restore StartLayout from unbootable Windows drive?
The only thing I found is a DefaultLayouts.xml file. But it contains only some default arrangement, not my customized arrangement.
File location:
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\DefaultLayouts.xml


For Win 7, it's shown at https://www.thewindowsclub.com/registry-tweaks-windows-7. That said, you'd need to open the Registry as another user, which has some issues.
